# how to run action of frontend controller from backend in yii2

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to run action of frontend controller from backend?

this code works if called action is in backend too. can i specify in runAction that controller/action is in frontend?

```
Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action')
```

Also i' m tried something like

```
$c=new controller();
$s->action();
```

too but it seems it not working too. //new controller() need some parameters and i have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yii\base\Application` object has a public property `controllerNamespace`, which defaults to `app\\controllers`. You need to change it accordingly to changing default controller namespace.

Change namespace in action:

> Yii::$app->controllerNamespace = 'frontend\controllers' and use runAction

Comment: thank u @Cap, work perfect. correct namespace is 'backend\controllers' with \

Comment: sorry, i've written from mobile

Answer (score 0):

A way could be this .

In your backend application config you could create an additional 'UrlManager' component 
name  eg:  urlManagerFrontEnd

```
  return [
      'components' => [
          'urlManager' => [
              // here is your backend URL rules
          ],
          'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
              'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
              'baseUrl' => 'http://your_path/frontend/web/index.php',
              'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
              'showScriptName' => false,
          ],

      ],
  ];
```

Then you should invoke following to compose front-end URL:

```
    Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl();
```

and add the controller/action you prefer

remeber that

```
runAction()
```

> Runs an action within this controller with the specified action ID and
>   parameters.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#runAction()-detail

this mean that cannot run an action of another controller or of another application ..

If you need  a service then you must configure a RESTFull or you simply need  a redirection you can use redirect

Comment: thanks but createurl() return a string like 'frontend/controller/action'. also using this string with runAction() won't work.

Comment: actually i need result from runAction() in backend controller.  i'm wondering how redirect can help?

Comment: @a.v   . i have update the answer  with some other brief comment .. hope is useful

Comment: thank u again @scaisedge, but i think "this mean that cannot run an action of another controller " is not true. if both of controllers are in backend or frontend it works (i tested) and im seraching for solution to call directly and without using curl or ...

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html#runAction()-detail , first parameter is $route. we can specify controller.